# Unity with GeForce FX 5200

Tags: 11.04, unity, nvidia

I have a computer with a Nvidia GeForce FX 5200

With the nvidia binary driver (version 173) my computer wont boot. I get a white screen with random black characters on it.

With the Experimental open source 3D support everything works expect that all the icons in the dock are not shown, (the dock still works, auto hides, hover help, clicks, etc works)[image]

How can I use Unity. (10.10 ran excellently with full compiz effects)

Comment: This bug seems to be tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/772207

Answer (score 2):

The Nvidia GeForce FX 5200 binary driver has been black listed due to the icon issue which effects both the open source and closed source drivers.

The good news is that owners of the Nvidia GeForce FX 5200 can still use unity without hardware acceleration by installing Unity 2d:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

The good news are I had the same problem and managed to fix it!
Please read my post on ubuntu forums here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11967978&postcount=4

Hope this helps!