# Hardware does not support unity after reboot

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)

I installed ubuntu natty on my friends laptop and it was all working fine out of the box, last night he updated the system and when he restarted, the message he got was this

```
Hardware does not support unity, going back to Gnome
```

This has happened on another friends system too, he had an NVIDIA card so i downloaded the driver from the dell site and when i ran the file, the whole GUI ceased to work, i don't want to go the windows way and re install to solve the problem. Please help, the laptop in question is a Dell Inspiron 14 series, the old one that does not have a discrete GPU.

Comment: Please update your question with details of your graphics card (lspci | grep VGA) - together with how you first installed any additional graphics drivers - and also what graphics drivers you manually downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Unity-2D by running the following commands may help you:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)