# My Ubuntu doesn't seem to be using Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity, drivers, via

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop. I upgraded from 10.04 several weeks ago. I noticed that it seems to be using the old GNOME 2 user interface.

I'm curious if this is because of my graphics card, which doesn't work with any graphics intensive programs, including Blender or KDE.

If it's any use, lspci | grep VGA gives me this output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. CN896/VN896/P4M900 [Chrome 9 HC] (rev 01)
```

Will Unity work on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 11.04 with a card that does not support 3D very well you will be greeted with the default Ubuntu desktop, not Unity.

There is a solution for you - use Unity2D!

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Then log out and when logging back in select "Unity 2D" at the bottom of the login screen.

[image]