# Ubuntu 11.04 still slow after upgrade

Tags: unity, performance

I had an amd athlon tf-20 cpu which was a single core that ran at 1.6GHz, 2 Gig ram and an HD 3200. Unity runs slow as hell. I upgraded my cpu to an amd turion tl-56 dual-core which runs at 1.8GHz, and Unity still runs slow. My sister's laptop of 5 years with an intel celeron dual-core runs unity way faster than my laptop. Can anyone suggest the problem here and a solution?...please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a decent graphic card and the corresponding drivers installed to run Unity.

If you don't have these then you can try Unity 2D (which will be a lot faster on a old graphic card), to install it on 11.04 :

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Then you restart and when logging in select "Unity 2D" instead of "Ubuntu".

Comment: But my sister's 5 year old crappy laptop runs ubuntu 11.04 very smooth.

Comment: Maybe she have an old NVidia graphic card (which are still supported by proprietary drivers) and you have an old ATI graphic card (which are not at all).

Comment: She has intel graphics and my ati chip is just 2 years old...don't know.