# Is there a start menu with a search box similar to the one in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search

At the moment even I'm using Natty version of Ubuntu, my virtualbox machine auto change the UI of startmenu that I would find the searchbox any more.

I'm looking for way to search & execute applications quickly like I do in Windows 7 - rather than looking for it by nake-eye with the classic menu

Please help if you know how. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: whilst not exactly a direct answer to your question - if you use something like "launchy" - you can search for applications and files from one window which you can start from a hotkey... you might want to consider this option and leave your menu as is rather than replacing it.  http://www.launchy.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install Unity 2D:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)

It's similar to Unity but built on Qt and doesn't need compiz to run. So, you will never miss it.

Another way to fix things is to figure out what happened to 3D-support in your Virtual Box. Seems like it turned off and that's why you got GNOME2 desktop as fallback.

BTW, don't install Gnome Shell if you not sure what are you doing. All things in 11.04 built on top of GNOME 2 and it will be hard to get back to Unity or Unity 2D if you install GNOME 3. It's ok to use Gnome Shell in 11.10.

Comment: You've just `1 reputation` but your knowledge should be hundreds ^_^ It works for me to install Unity-2D. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try the Mint Linux startup menu, there is a search box and it looks like it will fit your needs

[image]

There is a PPA for nauty so you can just add it and install it using these commands on a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/mintmenu && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mintmenu
```

Credits got to [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org) for maintaining the PPA.

Comment: It's a nice suggestion! I'll try. But I need to have a way back ie. is it possible to return to the current menu aftern switch to Mint one?

Comment: yeah, they are different packages, wont even share configs ie: you can have the 2 at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Do will provide the features you require http://do.davebsd.com/

Answer (score 1):

Both Gnome 3 and Unity provide a box with searching capability like that in Windows 7.

Comment: @Werewolfsp Then how can I get Unity/Gnome3 in my current auto-changed startmenu?

Comment: windows 7 has feature which Ubuntu and other Linux have

Comment: @Rajput I don't see the relation of your comment to my post :( Yes, I know there is/are; thank you but how to get the `search box` :D ?

Comment: I don't know which version of Ubuntu you are using. If you were using Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10, you would have got unity already. As for gnome 3. May be 'sudo apt-get install gnome-shell' would help you. Gnome 3 is new and the ATI driver (private) doesn't work quite well with it.

Comment: @Werewolflsp I use 11.04 Natty version as stated in my post. And I also, the Unity disappeared after my system update right after I set up Ubuntu in my VirtualBox. So the problem is how to turn it back right?

Answer (score 1):

You also might try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. Brings up a search box where you can enter either names of apllictions or exact paths. Woks in Gnome 2 by default

Comment: I try `Alt+F2` to seek for `Update Manager` but the list is empty right after I type `update` :) So I guess `Alt F2` is not working for me.

Comment: yea, unfortunately some programs are called different internally thanthe name presented to the user. typing "update" does nothing for me as well. but typing "goo" brings up chrome and google earth for me, for example