# How to increase the idle time that causes auto-lock to log in screen?

Tags: automation, lock-screen

At the moment I got Ubuntu on my VirtualBox and it seems to auto-lock very quickly. Everytime I switch to VirtualBox to use it, I always have to enter password.

How can I increase the auto-lock period, says to 8 hours :D ?

<sup>Edit</sup>
In Ocelot 11.10 just hit `screen` from dash box to see the screen-lock application.

I don't know how to do that in Natty 11.04

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to *System Settings* and select *screen*. Or type in *screen* in [Unity Dash](https://askubuntu.com/tags/unity-dash/info).

You'll get the following screen.

[image]

Set the time you want to set or switch it off :)

Comment: @Lad In system settings of mine as screenshot above, I can't find `Screen`. Please be more specific on that. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

Comment: can u type in screen in dash?

Comment: https://min.us/lThj66fiKQaWv

check this video

Comment: @Lad I have no `dash`

Comment: @Lad It's nice to see such simple & nice web min.us So it just to be Start Menu - System  Tools - System Setting - Screen. But your start menu is diff. from mine. What Linux distribution are you using? I'm using Natty 11.04

Comment: @Lad Though, after installed Unity-2D, I still cannot find `Screen` when enter screen to dash box.

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself by getting Ubuntu Unity `dash box` so as I can search & run the application from its keyword; via installing Unity-2D for my Natty 11.04 virtual machine (the Unity-3D doesn't work for me).

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Comment: Though, after installed Unity-2D, I still cannot find Screen when enter screen to dash box for Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

Answer (score 1):

To find the screen settings window as shown in the picture above click on the 'Applications' tab located on the top left corner of your screen (I am using Gnome).

Then System Tools --> System Settings --> Brightness & Lock.