# Which desktop environment to use if Unity test on 11.04 didn't run well on one test?

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm running now natty (Ubuntu 11.04) but the unity test fail on one topic although I have a Nvidia chip on my Dell 620.

Will I have a GNOME desktop after installing Ubuntu 11.10 although Unity did not run on my 11.04?

I can't trust the Live CD since it does not use the Nvidia proprietary drivers while running.

Comment: Jorge, Look at the question again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to run the Unity 2D in 11.10 
Here is a link for a tutorial http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/unity-2d-tweak-app-updated-for-11-10/

Comment: The information in that link is incorrect and for the wrong version of Ubuntu the asker asked for.

Comment: Re-read the question "Will I have a GNOME desktop after installing Ubuntu 11.10 although Unity did not run on my 11.04?" my answer directly effects 11.10 which was stated.

Comment: Can you check the link you posted though? It doesn't have anything to do with that, it's for some Unity 2d config tool

Comment: It has the download link for the tool to make the Unity settings easier.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to run Unity2D straight up after the installation.

It is installed by default with 11.10 and really will not care what driver your are using as long as you can boot to graphical login.

It is fast, almost as cute as Unity3D and will not hog your graphics card.

As an option will will also be able to run GNOME Classic session and make your desktop at least as similar as GNOME2 was. For more information on that have a look at this post

- [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)
- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop) (There is an answer there for 11.04 if you're interested in just using that)