# Why ubuntu 12.04 Operating System too slow..?

Tags: 12.04, performance, cpu, cpu-load

I was using `ubuntu 10.10` from last year. every thing was Ok with that. recently I've installed `Ubuntu 12.04` in place of `10.10`, after installing that on my `Dell laptop`, I started to feel uncomfortable.

It to slow event if you move mouse then its feel like i'll take 1min to move one place 2 another..

**I know why this is happening, all because of 12.04 runs my CPU up to 99%-100% all over time.**

And there are 2-3 processes who use all the cpu.. 
like
 **1.** `System_Monitor`
**2.** `compiz`
I don't know why its use all the CPU even Other app can't able to run ..  in `Ubuntu 10.10`  every think was Ok..

Any solution for this problem..!! |

Thank's

Comment: And what might those 2-3 processes be?

Comment: Please detail in your question the specifications of your laptop in terms of Memory (RAM), HDD space, swap, CPU type, graphics card,graphics driver.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, the model of laptop (DELL has plenty of different models) would be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Not talking about 100% cpu here but this bug is responsible for significant cpu usage on 12.04:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/803943?comments=all

Fix is URGENTLY needed. But until that is available, no solution seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem with the graphics card. Check if there are restricted drivers for your GPU, more on this here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedDrivers.

If you have an old computer try Unity 2d, you can follow these instructions [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)