# Problem with Ubuntu 12.04 after installation

Tags: gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC, but when I boot Ubuntu, it simply shows the wallpaper, not any menus or other form of interface. My keyboard does nothing. What can I do to alleviate the situation?

Comment: Stupid question ; what happens if you push the mouse pointer up against the left hand side of the screen?

Comment: It seems like your graphics aren't in order. Enter the system in recovery mode (when you boot select recovery mode. and there try Yumi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are having problems with graphics acceleration?

I suggest you try "ctrl+alt+F2", you should see a text terminal. Then install unity 2d using:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Then restart with:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I tried with "ctrl+alt+f2" it works, it shows me this
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "name" tty2
"name" login: Then i put my login
password: Then I can't type anything here :S

Comment: I'm sorry in advance if this question is dumb to you: you know that in linux, when you type a password in a terminal, it shows nothing   right? (no asterisks like in windows: ****) You just type the password and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Sometimes these types of problem, run away with updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing Ubuntu 2D from the login screen. From there you can investigate any driver issues with your graphics card, if any. I actually prefer Ubuntu 2D.