# Ubuntu 12.04 "stuttering"

Tags: 12.04

When I log in to the desktop Ubuntu seems to "stutter". Doing pretty much anything causes the cursor to freeze for a few seconds, and the rest of the screen updates something like every 15 seconds (during these 15 seconds I can still move the cursor). For example, opening the home folder I first see no effect, followed by a semi-transparent home folder, and finally the folder as it should be (this can take like 30 seconds); no animation, just three individual frames. Also, I sometimes don't see a window for a program, even though the program in question is supposed to be "up".

Since this is my first experience of Linux, I confess I have no idea where to start - searching the web I only found problems with complete freezes/crashes requiring rebooting, as opposed to this "stuttering".

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32bit from a bootable USB stick a couple of days ago, right after a fresh Vista 32bit install.  Thinking the stuttering might stop if I updated Ubuntu, I managed to install approx 270 updates through the Update Manager, but the stuttering was still there.  Apart from the updates, I haven't installed any software other than what was included on the bootable USB stick.

Vista and Ubuntu are on a single Crucial m4 SSD, in a dual-boot setup, with GRUB.
CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 
GPU: Nvidia GeForce 8800 GTX (with the recommended proprietary drivers)
RAM: 2GB DDR2

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the graphics driver. Try selecting "Ubuntu 2D" in the login screen as a (possible) temporary workaround. Then try selecting the other available driver options in the driver selection tool. (It should show up if you type "jockey" into the dash.)

Comment: You were absolutely right - Ubuntu 2D gave me the opportunity to change to the other proprietary graphics driver, and now it works!

Comment: @Béné you need to post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Totte you should accept his answer after it it posted if it worked for you, that way other users know that the question was solved.

Comment: Okay, I added my comment as an answer. Glad it fixed it for you, Totte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with the graphics driver. Try selecting "Ubuntu 2D" in the login screen as a temporary workaround. [(How to change to Unity 2D.)](https://askubuntu.com/a/64236/21008)

Then try selecting the other available driver options in the driver selection tool. (It should show up if you type "jockey" into the dash.)