# Hardware not suitable for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I want to upgrade to 12.04 but the system tells me my graphics card won't run it. Is there a way of getting round this, or do I need to look for a different distribution (a hardware upgrade is not a financially viable option).

Comment: would be nice if you tell us what hardware u use. otherwise we can't help you. and you are upgrading to 12.04 from 11.10 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was asking more in general terms - I have 2 machines with Tango Studio (a variation on Ubuntu Studio) and the developers appear to be suggesting going to a new distribution (as they have). If Unity is the only way forward I'll have to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware most likely doesn't meet [the requirements for Unity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements). However, up until Ubuntu 12.04 you have alternative of [Unity 2D.](https://bfiller.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/unity-2d/)

> Unity 2D’s main goal is to provide a Unity environment on hardware
>   platforms that don’t  support Unity’s Open GL requirements.

It's installed by default and you can [easily switch to using it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop) instead of regular Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have 2 machines with Tango Studio (a variation on Ubuntu Studio) and the developers appear to be suggesting going to a new distribution (as they have). If Unity is the only way forward (after 12.04) I'll have to switch, if I'm going to upgrade I might as well follow them. It does seem a little odd though, as 'running on anything' was Linux's great claim to fame!