# Unity runs slow, how can I improve its performance?

Tags: unity, performance

I like how Unity looks but I have 2 problems:

1. **Unity 3D**
   When I login with Unity 3D, my pc becomes slower, I got an AMD II X3 with 2GB of RAM, Nvidia Gforce 6150SE nForce 430/PCI/SSE2 integrated.
   When I try to open the dash, take a lot of time to open, most often takes up to 5 seconds and while its opening remains fuzzy and unreacted, even the apps or folders take the same time to open and the same reaction.
2. **Unity 2D**
   When I login with Unity 2D my pc goes more faster, the only problem is that i cant configure Unity as I want, I try to configure the Unity plugin in CCSM.
   For eg: I changed "hide Launcher" to: Never. It does not save changes, even when I restart my computer.

I don't know if the problem is with Unity 3D or with my pc.

Comment: Sorry is Nvidia Gforce 6150SE nForce 430/PCI/SSE2

Comment: Your English is good, I think I understood what you were trying to say.

Comment: I think this question should be updated for 12.10+ and checked to see if the answers still apply.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In CCSM, go into the options for **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** and in the tab **Experimental**, change option **Dash Blur** from "Active Blur" to "Static Blur" or "No Blur".

You can also go into option **Composite** and disable "Detect Refresh Rate" and increase option **Refresh Rate** to *over* 60.

To increase performance further, you have to have **Nvidia's propietary drivers** installed (make sure you are using the **latest version**). Go into **NVIDIA X Server Settings** and in **Open GL Settings** Change "Image Settings" to "High Performance".

**Remember these options will only apply with **Unity 3D****

Comment: Changing the `Dash blush` even to None had significant improvements on my machine.

Comment: Thanks i follow all ur steps but as Emil Ivanov even dont had significant improvements on my machine too :( even i got one more problem u can see right here "https://picasaweb.google.com/107400471364555567604/1110#5666525281985304738" as u can see the icons are incomplete, can u help me with this?

Comment: try restart unity. Run command: "unity --replace"

Answer (score 3):

You cannot ust CCSM to configure the Unity-2D since it is not using compiz to show Unity. You have to use dconf-editor or you can use this tool :

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/ubuntu-unity-2d-tweaking-tool-lets-you-adjust-the-launcher-dash-enable-compositing/

Hope this helps.

Luis Da Costa

Comment: Tks for ur answer i will try and tell u

Comment: Tks again, i with try 2D-Unity-settings and works good, i can configure it in my 2D performance, now how can i configure desktop effects?  its not posible in unity 2D, i'm trying with CCSM but nothing.

Comment: I don't think you can configure de desktop effect (but I can be wrong), since, like I said earlier Unity-2D do not use Compiz so when using Unity-2D CCSM is useless... you only have 2 solutions :
1 - The software that I show you in my post.
2 - The gconf/dconf settings (but I can't really help with that since I am not using Unity-2D ... sorry :S)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing with ati-drivers is a problem because some drivers do not support the procedures "GLX_EXT_texture_from_bitmap" it is necessary to work AIGLX. if there is no AIGLX everything goes through XGL, including 3D and therefore slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `nvidia-96` drivers. Unity 3d works fine for me after that.

Also, Compiz tweaks will help.

Comment: thanks but still same, can you write the steps that you use to install nvidia-96, you did using synaptic?

Comment: just used "additional drivers"

Answer (score -1):

Try using the CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) to disable other plugins first.

Does that help?

Comment: Tks for ur answer.
already try this method and doesnt work, i cant edit anything with CCSM